# XSD validation for continous digits

Tags: xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I have below element where i do not want continuation of more than 3 digits any where in the string. How can i do that using pattern or any other way. Thanks.

e.g John - Valid,    123 John- Valid,    123John - valid,    1230John -
 Invalid , Jo1284hn - Invalid ,
    John1734 - Invalid

```
<xs:element name="FirstName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">           
        <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **XSD 1.1 you can use assertions**

```
<xs:element name="FirstName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">           
            <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xs:assertion test="not(matches($value, '\d{4}'))"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But you can do it **even in XSD 1.0 using `xs:pattern`**:

```xml
<xs:element name="FirstName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">           
            <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xs:pattern value="\d{0,3}(\D+\d{0,3})*|(\d{0,3}\D+)+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Or if you prefer it, you can separate the patterns:

```xml
<xs:element name="FirstName" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">           
            <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <!-- Matches every strings (optionally starting with 0 to 3 digits) and optionally followed by [(non digits) + (0 to 3 digits)] n times -->
            <xs:pattern value="\d{0,3}(\D+\d{0,3})*"/>
            <!-- Matches every strings ending with a non-digit and not containing more than 3 continuous digits -->
            <xs:pattern value="(\d{0,3}\D+)+"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: tried with string 235First123name45 but doesn't match. I should i have given this in examples above.

Comment: That was my fault. I've corrected and tested both expressions (it was pending) and simplified the XSD 1.1 version.